# Count characters and substring in words

Tags: delphi

I have to read an unknown quantity of words and terminate the program when the word "last" is typed in. 
I have to:

- Display the number of names that begin a with "S".
- Display the number of names that end a with "d".
- Display the number of names that end with "anne".

Problem: The only problem I have is displaying the number of names that end with "anne". It displays 0, except if I only enter the word "anne", then it displays 1.

Note:

- We haven't started with arrays.
- This is work I'm practising before I write my test, it's not homework that should be handed in.

My code:

```
unit Ess_U;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    redOut: TRichEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var wrd : string;
    Scount, dcount, Namecount : integer;
begin
redOut.clear;
   Scount := 0;
   dcount := 0;
   Namecount := 0;


   repeat
    wrd := inputbox ('Input words', 'Enter any word', '');

    if (Pos('S',wrd) > 0) AND (wrd[1] = 'S') then
     begin
     inc(Scount);
     end

    else if (Pos('d',wrd) > 0) AND (wrd[length(wrd)] = 'd') then
     begin
     inc(dcount);
     end

    else if copy(wrd, length(wrd)-4,4) = 'anne' then
     begin
     inc(Namecount);
     end;

    until (wrd = 'last');

    redOut.Lines.Add ('The number of names that begin with the letter "S" is ' + inttostr(Scount));
    redOut.Lines.Add ('The number of names that end with the letter "d"  is ' + inttostr(dcount));
    redOut.Lines.Add ('The number of names that begin with "anne" is ' + inttostr(Namecount));
end;

end.

enter code here
```

Comment: In programming it is essential to pay attention to details, to a degree that can almost be called nitpicking. So, here's my 'nitpicks' regarding the **definition** of your task. You say that the user enters *words* and then you are supposed to count *names* that have some special features. Ok, I can accept that names are words, but all words are not names. For eample, is 'Sorry' a name? Not in my book, but you seem to count it as one. To do what your definition says, you would need a list of all existing names from which you could lookup the entered word to verify if it's a name or not.

Comment: A peculiarity in your **implementation** is when e.g. the name 'Susanne' is entered. It starts with 'S' so you count it according to rule one, but should it not also be counted according to rule three? Because you have a chain of `if then else if then else ...` Susanne is not counted as being an '...anne' name. I hope Susanne doesn't feel bad about this.

Comment: A final nitpick is the last `redOut.Lines.Add(...` line. It says *...begin with "anne"...` while your task definition says '...end with "anne".' Anyway, +1 for your attempt and for being open about the motivation for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `StartsText` and `EndsText` from `StrUtils` to check if a string starts or ends with a text, instead of manually calling `Pos` and `Copy`. (or `AnsiStartsText` and `AnsiEndsText`)

Add `StrUtils` to your uses clause and change the section with conditions like that:

```
 ...
 uses StrUtils, ...;
 ...

 if (StartsText('S', wrd)) then
 begin
   Inc(Scount);
 end

 if (EndsText('d', wrd)) then
 begin
   Inc(dcount);
 end

 if (StartsText('anne', wrd)) then
 begin
   Inc(Namecount);
 end;
```

The `StrUtils` unit has the following useful routines:

> - [StartsText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.StrUtils.StartsText) - determines if the substring `ASubText` begins the string `AText`, case insensitive comparison;
> - [StartsStr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.StrUtils.StartsStr) - same as `StartsText`, but case sensitive;
> - [EndsText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.StrUtils.EndsText) - determines if the substring `ASubText` ends the string `AText`, case insensitive comparison;
> - [EndsStr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.StrUtils.EndsStr) - same as `EndsStr`, but case sensitive;

Answer (score 6):

You've already had an answer that shows you another way to do what you were attempting, using library functions.  That's fine (assuming your Delphi version has them), but there's an unresolved aspect to your question.

You said "Problem: The only problem I have is displaying the number of names that end with "anne". It displays 0, except if I only enter the word "anne", then it displays 1."

Now, a key part of coding is learning to debug, and a key part of that is accurate observation and knowing to construct a reproducible test case.

Try this:

Change the first line of your `repeat` loop to read:

```
wrd := 'xanne'; //inputbox ('Input words', 'Enter any word', '');
```

and change the test for 'anne' to read

```
else begin
  wrd := copy(wrd, length(wrd)-4,4);
  Caption := wrd;
  if wrd = 'anne' then
    begin
     inc(Namecount);
    end;
end;
```

then, put a breakpoint on the line

```
  wrd := copy(wrd, length(wrd)-4,4);
```

and press `F9` to compile and run your program.

When the debugger stops at the breakpoint, keep pressing `F8` (to single-step through the code.

You'll soon see what's wrong, namely that

```
 copy(wrd, length(wrd)-4,4)
```

does not equal 'anne' when wrd starts off as 'xanne'.  I'll leave you to work out why not, because I think you'll find that a bit more instructive than just finding out about a new-to-you library function.

Btw, this sort of thing tends to happen when you try testing a program by typing inputs over and over.  That's why I've said to modify you code temporarily, so that you're starting from a known input, not one you may have mistyped (or even had the CapsLock on by mistake and not noticed).